# How can I update the BIOS of a Dell Inspiron 1564?

Tags: bios, dell-inspiron

How can I update the BIOS of my Dell Inspiron 1564?

Comment: Usually before you ask something though, you want to look at the support site for your product. Dell BIOS updates are incredibly easy to do. Go on their site and look around.

Comment: What Mark said. BIOS updates are so easy now. It's an installer you download and then run, just like that.

Answer (score 3):

Dell's [support](http://support.dell.com) website has a [program to update the BIOS](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/format.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&s=bsd&deviceid=23161&libid=1&releaseid=R274790&vercnt=1&formatcnt=0&SystemID=INSPIRON1564&servicetag=&os=W764&osl=en&catid=-1&dateid=-1&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&impid=-1&checkFormat=true).

Download the file, save it to your desktop, restart your laptop in Safe Mode, then execute the the file you saved earlier, when it is done, restart the laptop normally.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what OS you are running but if you are within Windows go to this site and download the BIOS update.

> http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&cs=RC1084719&l=en&s=k12&os=WW1&osl=en&SystemID=INSPIRON1564&catid=-1&impid=-1

Once downloaded just run it and reboot, easy as that.